# A counter example, topology question

Tags: calculus, general-topology, examples-counterexamples

Im looking for a counter example for the following problem:

Let $ S_{1}\neq\emptyset $ be a compact set and $S_{2}\neq\emptyset $ a closed set.
(Those are subsets of $ \mathbb{R}^n $ for some $ n $).

So there exists $ s_{1}\in S_{1},\thinspace\thinspace\thinspace s_{2}\in S_{2} $ such that for the distance between the sets:

$ d\left(S_{1},S_{2}\right):=\inf_{x_{1}\in S_{1},x_{2}\in S_{2}}d\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right) $

we have $ \inf_{x_{1}\in S_{1},x_{2}\in S_{2}}d\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right)=d\left(s_{1},s_{2}\right) $

Originally this was a prove/disprove question, but Im pretty sure that this is false, so Im looking for a counter example. Thanks in advance.

After reading the comments:

This is my attempt to prove the statement (rather then disprove it):

Let $ d\left(x_{n}^{1},x_{n}^{2}\right)$ be a sequence such that $ \lim_{n\to\infty}d\left(x_{n}^{1},x_{n}^{2}\right)=\inf_{x_{1}\in S_{1},x_{2}\in S_{2}}d\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right) $.

Since $S_1 $ is compact, there exists a convergent subsequence of $ x_{n}^{1} $, say $ x_{n_{k}}^{1} $.Denote its limit by $ x_1 $. One can verify that

$ d\left(x^{1},x_{n_{k}}^{2}\right)\underset{n\to\infty}{\longrightarrow}\inf_{x_{1}\in S_{1},x_{2}\in S_{2}}d\left(x_{1},x_{2}\right) $

I tried to prove that $ x_{n_{k}}^{2} $ also have a convergent sequence and that would end the proof. But I cant see how.

Comment: Isn't $S_2=\emptyset$ a counterexample

Comment: @79037662 I dont know, whats the distance between a compact set and the empty set? we havent defined it, but anyway I'll edit the post and add the requirment that the sets are not empty.

Comment: Well that's irrelevant, since "there exists $s_2\in S_2$" is already false when $S_2=\emptyset$. But I believe $\inf\emptyset=\infty$ by definition.

Comment: @79037662 Do you have non trivial counter example?

Comment: If $S_1$ and $S_2$ are nonempty, there is no counterexample. The statement is true.

Comment: Since you have metric $d$ here, the notion "compact" and "sequentially compact" can be interchanged here.  You can simply make use of the property of $\inf$ to construct two sequences in $S_1$ and $S_2$, and make some technical work to extract a convergent subsequence.

Comment: @GNUSupporter8964民主女神地下教會 Thats what I tried actually but I couldnt finish the proof. can you look at the post again? I wrote down my attempt.

Comment: You're very near.  Recall that sequential compactness is equivalent to closed and bounded in metric spaces, so you need the boundedness of $(x^2_{n_k})_k$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's true now with the nonempty condition

Note that a subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is compact $\iff$ it is closed and bounded $\iff$ it is sequentially compact

The first important step is to realise that we can make it so that we only care about a bounded part of $S_2$

Choose any $x_1 \in S_1$ and $x_2 \in S_2$ to get an upper bound $D ≔ d(x_1, x_2)$ on $d(S_1, S_2)$

Since $S_1$ is bounded, it is contained in some large closed ball $\overline{B}(0, M)$

Hence the only points that we care about from $S_2$ are going to be within a distance $D$ of this ball

That is to say, we can w.l.o.g. consider ${S_2}' ≔ S_2 \cap \overline{B}(0, M+D)$ instead of $S_2$, which is now (sequentially) compact

From here we can take a sequence of pairs $a_n \in S_1$ and $b_n \in S_2$ with $d(a_n, b_n) \rightarrow d(S_1, S_2)$, and appeal to sequential compactness of our sets and continuity of $d$ to find the desired pair of points

Comment: I see, thanks, that helps a lot.